# Elixir: How to convert a keyword list to a map?

Tags: json, elixir

I have a keyword list of Ecto changeset errors I'd like to convert to a map so that the Poison JSON parser can correctly output a list of validation errors in the JSON format.

I get a list of errors as follows:

```
[:topic_id, "can't be blank", :created_by, "can't be blank"]
```

...and I'd like to get a map of errors like so:

```
%{topic_id: "can't be blank", created_by: "can't be blank"}
```

Alternatively, if I could convert it to a list of strings, I could use that as well.

What is the best way to accomplish either of these tasks?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What you have there isn't a keyword list, it is just a list with every odd element representing a key and every even element representing a value.

The difference is:

```
[:topic_id, "can't be blank", :created_by, "can't be blank"] # List
[topic_id: "can't be blank", created_by: "can't be blank"]   # Keyword List
```

A keyword list can be turned into a map using [Enum.into/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2)

```
Enum.into([topic_id: "can't be blank", created_by: "can't be blank"], %{})
```

Since your data structure is a list, you can convert it using [Enum.chunk_every/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2) and [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)

```
[:topic_id, "can't be blank", :created_by, "can't be blank"]
|> Enum.chunk_every(2)
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn ([key, val], acc) -> Map.put(acc, key, val) end)
```

You can read more about Keyword lists at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/maps-and-dicts.html

Comment: I can't try it out right now, but I have a feeling that you should be able to reduce the last example to `[...] |> Enum.chunk(2) |> Enum.into(%{})`

Comment: Ah, I missed difference between a list and a keyword list.  Thanks!

Comment: I also am having the same problem as OP, only I believe Changeset has changed its implementation. ATOW the changeset errors _is_ a keyword list, e.g. `[field_1: {"is invalid", [type: Ecto.UUID]}, field_2: {"can't be blank", []}]`. I was able to convert to a map using this answer's `Enum.into` approach with `error_map = Enum.into(changeset.errors, %{})`. As a map, I could then get my message with `{err_msg, _type} = Map.fetch!(error_map, :field_1)`.

Comment: This works for me: `[topic_id: "can't be blank", created_by: "can't be blank"]
|> Enum.into(%{})`. Seemingly no need for the chunk.

Comment: @RyanBigg Well spotted. I was using the wrong data structure in the last example.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do this is by combining `Enum.chunk/2` with `Enum.into/3`. For example:

```
[:topic_id, "can't be blank", :created_by, "can't be blank"]
|> Enum.chunk(2)
|> Enum.into(%{}, fn [key, val] -> {key, val} end)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way to do that is by using of list comprehension:

```
iex> list = [:topic_id, "can't be blank", :created_by, "can't be blank"]
iex> map = for [key, val] <- Enum.chunk(list, 2), into: %{}, do: {key, val}
%{created_by: "can't be blank", topic_id: "can't be blank"}
```

Besides you can convert your list to keyword list:

```
iex> klist = for [key, val] <- Enum.chunk(list, 2), do: {key, val}
[topic_id: "can't be blank", created_by: "can't be blank"]
```

It could be also useful in some cases.

You can read more about this use case at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#results-other-than-lists